# Delete multiple Redis stream id with Jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

how can i delete multi redis stream id with jedis?

they have a methods calls "xdel" -

```
xdel(String key, StreamEntryID... ids)
XDEL key ID [ID ...]
```

what is the type that i need to send to the method to delete multi key?
i declare List but the method didnt get this type.

i got this error -

```
method redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.xdel(java.lang.String,redis.clients.jedis.StreamEntryID...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; java.util.stream.Stream<redis.clients.jedis.StreamEntryID> cannot be converted to redis.clients.jedis.StreamEntryID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jedis `xdel` method takes varags of StreamEntryID. So you can do only following two:

1.

```
String key;
StreamEntryID id1, id2, ..., idN;
...
jedis.xdel(key, id1, id2, ..., idN);
```

2. 

```
String key;
StreamEntryID[] ids;
...
jedis.xdel(key, ids);
```

But you're sending Stream of StreamEntryID. You can consider changing your Stream (`Stream<StreamEntryID>`) to array (`StreamEntryID[]`).